# How do I extract the characters in between the specific set of characters in a string python(regex)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I have been trying to extract image source link, order_detail link, cost(rupee) and name of the product from a html(not formatted and is multiline).
I have tried many solution, which are mostly startswith and endswith but none worked.
Below is the sample division(please copy to a notepad).

```
txt = """div>
    <div class="ShLswe">
       <a class="_2WFi0x" href="/order_details?order_id=OD40818094004&amp;item_id=OD408180940040000&amp;unit_id=OD408180940040000000">
          <div class="row">
             <div class="col-6-12">
                <div class="row">
                   <div class="col-3-12">
                      <div class="J2h1WZ">
                         <div class="_3BTv9X" style="height: 75px; width: 75px;"><img class="_1Nyybr  _30XEf0" alt="" src="https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/image/75/75/usb-adaptor/s/9/8/tp-link-150-mbps-wireless-n-original-imad8rruefj6rf3y.jpeg"></div>
                      </div>
                   </div>
                   <div class="col-8-12">
                      <div class="_3D-3p2">
                         <span class="row _13y4_y _1iu0PI">TP-LINK 150 Mbps TL-WN721N Wireless N</span>
                         <div class="row _3i00zY"><span class="_3i00zY _2n1WrW">Seller: </span><span class="_2dTbPB">WS Retail</span></div>
                      </div>
                   </div>
                </div>
             </div>
             <div class="col-2-12 JL36Xz">₹512</div>
             <div class="col-4-12 _3Yi3bU">
                <div>
                   <div class="_30ud5x _3ELbo9"></div>
                   <span class="_7BRRQk">Delivered on Aug 20, 2014</span>
                   <div class="_2t-3dH">Your item has been delivered</div>
                </div>
                <div class="d-uGDa"></div>
                <div class="paz6BF">
                   <div class="_1S3Y5S row">
       <a class="FlPMmo"><img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB3aWR0aD0nMTYnIGhlaWdodD0nMTknIHZlcnNpb249IjEuMSIgeG1sbnM9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDAvc3ZnIiB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgMTggMTgiPgoJPGcgZmlsbD0nbm9uZSc+CgkJPHBvbHlnb24gaWQ9IlNoYXBlIiBmaWxsPSIjMjg3NEYxIiBwb2ludHM9IjkgMTIuMDYyNSAxMy42Mzc1IDE1LjQzNzUgMTEuODYyNSA5Ljk4NzUgMTYuNSA2LjY4NzUgMTAuODEyNSA2LjY4NzUgOSAxLjA2MjUgNy4xODc1IDYuNjg3NSAxLjUgNi42ODc1IDYuMTM3NSA5Ljk4NzUgNC4zNjI1IDE1LjQzNzUiIC8+CgkJPHBvbHlnb24gaWQ9IlNoYXBlIiBwb2ludHM9IjAgMCAxOCAwIDE4IDE4IDAgMTgiIC8+Cgk8L2c+Cjwvc3ZnPg==" class="_3Q4GqT col-1-5"><span class="_3zvrLw col-3-5">Rate &amp; Review Product</span></a></div></div></div></div></a>
    </div>
    </div>"""

    x = re.match(r'^<img class="_1Nyybr  _30XEf0" alt="" src="(.*?)\.jpeg$', txt)

    print(x)
```

Output is none

Note: the above txt contains same patterns(class names) as the other divisions

1) image = start:  `<img class="_1Nyybr  _30XEf0" alt="" src="` end: `.jpeg` or `">`

needed characters: `https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/image/75/75/usb-adaptor/s/9/8/tp-link-150-mbps-wireless-n-original-imad8rruefj6rf3y.jpeg`

2) Name = start:  `<span class="row _13y4_y _1iu0PI">` end: `</span>`

needed characters: `TP-LINK 150 Mbps TL-WN721N Wireless N`

3) cost = start:  `<div class="col-2-12 JL36Xz">₹` end: `</div>`

needed characters: `512`

All of the above are very similar and the solution will be too, but the string is very vague I get lot of errors while manipulating it.
I just need to extract the needed characters and store it in a list. Any approach is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Why not use a proper HTML parser for at least part of this?

Comment: Regarding the regex, remove `^` and `$` and use `re.search`.

Comment: you can use [beautiful soup](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) for doing this all easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re

txt = """div><div class="ShLswe"><a class="_2WFi0x" href="/order_details?order_id=OD40818094004&amp;item_id=OD408180940040000&amp;unit_id=OD408180940040000000"><div class="row"><div class="col-6-12"><div class="row"><div class="col-3-12"><div class="J2h1WZ"><div class="_3BTv9X" style="height: 75px; width: 75px;"><img class="_1Nyybr  _30XEf0" alt="" src="https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/image/75/75/usb-adaptor/s/9/8/tp-link-150-mbps-wireless-n-original-imad8rruefj6rf3y.jpeg"></div></div></div><div class="col-8-12"><div class="_3D-3p2"><span class="row _13y4_y _1iu0PI">TP-LINK 150 Mbps TL-WN721N Wireless N</span><div class="row _3i00zY"><span class="_3i00zY _2n1WrW">Seller: </span><span class="_2dTbPB">WS Retail</span></div></div></div></div></div><div class="col-2-12 JL36Xz">₹512</div><div class="col-4-12 _3Yi3bU"><div><div class="_30ud5x _3ELbo9"></div><span class="_7BRRQk">Delivered on Aug 20, 2014</span><div class="_2t-3dH">Your item has been delivered</div></div><div class="d-uGDa"></div><div class="paz6BF"><div class="_1S3Y5S row"><a class="FlPMmo"><img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB3aWR0aD0nMTYnIGhlaWdodD0nMTknIHZlcnNpb249IjEuMSIgeG1sbnM9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDAvc3ZnIiB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgMTggMTgiPgoJPGcgZmlsbD0nbm9uZSc+CgkJPHBvbHlnb24gaWQ9IlNoYXBlIiBmaWxsPSIjMjg3NEYxIiBwb2ludHM9IjkgMTIuMDYyNSAxMy42Mzc1IDE1LjQzNzUgMTEuODYyNSA5Ljk4NzUgMTYuNSA2LjY4NzUgMTAuODEyNSA2LjY4NzUgOSAxLjA2MjUgNy4xODc1IDYuNjg3NSAxLjUgNi42ODc1IDYuMTM3NSA5Ljk4NzUgNC4zNjI1IDE1LjQzNzUiIC8+CgkJPHBvbHlnb24gaWQ9IlNoYXBlIiBwb2ludHM9IjAgMCAxOCAwIDE4IDE4IDAgMTgiIC8+Cgk8L2c+Cjwvc3ZnPg==" class="_3Q4GqT col-1-5"><span class="_3zvrLw col-3-5">Rate &amp; Review Product</span></a></div></div></div></div></a></div></div>"<"""


regex = re.compile(r"<img class=\"_1Nyybr  _30XEf0\" alt=\"\" src=\"(?P<image>.+?)\.jpeg.*<span class=\"row _13y4_y _1iu0PI\">(?P<name>.+?)</span>.*<div class=\"col-2-12 JL36Xz\">\D*(?P<cost>\d+?)</div>")

result = regex.search(txt)
print(result.group("image"))
print(result.group("name"))
print(result.group("cost"))
```

The output is:

```
https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/image/75/75/usb-adaptor/s/9/8/tp-link-150-mbps-wireless-n-original-imad8rruefj6rf3y
TP-LINK 150 Mbps TL-WN721N Wireless N
512
```